# CSS bottom align and push top content

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV with `min-height`. Inside two DIVs `.top` and `.bottom`. I'm using `position:absolute;bottom:0` to align `.bottom` to the bottom. The problem comes when the top or bottom content is too long. This image is best explained:

[image]

Here you can see the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/kurtko/5hrxhmku/1/

Any ideas?

Comment: What would be the desired behaviour?

Comment: It is compulsary to use position:absolute for bottom div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can easily be done with flexbox:

On the container just add

```
.item {
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

and on the bottom element add:

```
.bottom {
    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/5hrxhmku/12/)

```css
.item {
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}
.top {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.bottom {
  background-color: yellow;
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip.</div>
  <div class="bottom">Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.</div>
  <div class="bottom">Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident.</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="top">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</div>
  <div class="bottom">Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

if you want to this result than  you can change your **css** used `table` property and change your `html` **check to  demo**

```
.item {border:1px solid black;min-height:200px;position:relative;width:200px;margin-bottom:10px;display:table;}

.top {display:table-row;vertical-align:top;background-color:#ddd}

.bottom {background-color:yellow;display:table-cell;vertical-align:bottom;}
```

**=============Demo**

```css
.item {border:1px solid black;min-height:200px;position:relative;width:200px;margin-bottom:10px;display:table;}

.top {display:table-row;vertical-align:top;}
.top>div{background-color:#ddd}
.bottom>div {background-color:yellow;}
.bottom {display:table-cell;vertical-align:bottom;}
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <div class="top">
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <div>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <div class="top">
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <div>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident.</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <div class="top">
        <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <div>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5hrxhmku/13/)**

**CSS:**

```
.item {
    border:1px solid black;
    min-height:200px;
    display:flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width:200px;
    margin-bottom:10px
}
.top {
    background-color:#ddd;
    align-self: flex-start;
}
.bottom {
    background-color:yellow;
    align-self: flex-end;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly the same as what I posted?